# Machine Learning / Deep learning using Mathematica?

Tags: data, dataset, machine-learning

I am looking forward to the recommendation to learn ML/DL in Mathematica

I know that there are plenty of resources web sites and books, MOOC to learn Machine Learning and Deep Learning mostly in Python.

However, I am so curious to know how to learn and code using Mathematica.

Wellcome and thankful for interesting comments about what version it works, libraries, books, tutorials, ebooks, etc for Mathematica users.

Comment: Voting to close, since the question is pretty well answered in Mathematica's documentation. That said, I do not feel strongly about closing the question: 65%.

Comment: Some resources may be found in the [Wolfram U machine learning reference materials](https://www.wolfram.com/wolfram-u/catalog/machine-learning/).

Comment: Thanks, @DanielLichtblau